# Why am getting inferred latches?

Tags: vhdl

I am aware that inferred latches occur when not every possible path is defined, but I have made considerations to avoid this in my process:

The signal is:

```
signal BothButtons : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) ;
```

The process is:

```
Signaling : process(button0, button1)
begin

    if (button0= '0') AND (button1 = '0') then
        BothButtons <= "00";
    elsif (button0= '0') AND (button1 = '1') then
        BothButtons <= "01";
    elsif (button0= '1') AND (button1 = '0') then
        BothButtons <= "10";
    elsif (button0= '1') AND (button1 = '1') then
        BothButtons <= "11";    
    end if;
end process;
```

This is driving me crazy, any help is appreciated, maybe I lack an understanding of something really simple!

The error is:

> Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning at swDisplay.vhd(28): inferring latch(es) for signal or variable "BothButtons", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the process

As far as I am aware I am not assigning to the signal two values at the same time, rather it is in receiving values in different situations?

this time I am using that previous signal to drive the output of another process but another latch is appearing within it, this time I did take into account any other value and place an "else" statement to take care of that but no luck:

```
Counting : process(BothButtons) 

variable count0 : integer range 0 to 9; -- to hold the counter value

begin 


if BothButtons = "00" then
           count0 := 0;
elsif BothButtons = "01" then
           count0 := count0 + 1;
elsif BothButtons = "10" then
            count0 := count0;
elsif BothButtons = "11" then
            count0 := count0;
else
               count0 := 0;
end if;
```

For those of you who are wondering, yes this is part of an academic exercise!

Comment: What happens if `button0` is neither '0' nor '1'? There's your latch. (ditto button1) Now what do you need that `BothButtons <= button0 & button1;` doesn't do?

Comment: @BrianDrummond oh you mean in the event these two buttons had a floating value that neither is high or low? thank this did fix my issue, do please include it as an answer so I can select it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if button0 is neither '0' nor '1'? There's your latch. (ditto button1) Even `'H'` and `'L'` will confuse it, even though these have a clear meaning to you or me...

Now what do you need that `BothButtons <= button0 & button1;` doesn't do? (I may have misunderstood the problem you are having)

Comment: please refer to my updated question as I faced a similar issue somewhere else!

Comment: In the second process you directly ask for a latch. I recommend learning about clocked processes at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You have latches because you have a process with memory without a clock.

In the first example you give you just need an `else` in the end of the if-case. Otherwise it is forced to use a previous value, which requires that it has some memory of this previous value. Memory requires latches or flip-flops - and without a clock it is forced to use latches.

In the second example the lines `count0 := count0 + 1;` and `count0 := count0;` uses the value from a previous iteration of the process. This requires memory. And memory without a clock gives you latches.

Comment: Thanks, i'll go ahead and hook up the clock, I have already solved the first one thanks to the first answer!

Comment: Thanks my compiler and FPGA were screaming out of happiness when I introduced it! what would you recommend for going deep into VHDL, the on-line resources don't tell you about things such as this one?

Comment: Forget about online resources. You need a pretty deep understanding of the underlying logic to be able to program any VHDL programs usable outside of a simulator. When I was getting into VHDL I was using `Digital Design (VHDL): An Embedded Systems Approach Using VHDL` by Peter J. Ashenden. It will teach you the logic aspect along with the VHDL. I do not know if there's anything better today - but it is pretty good if you are new in all this stuff.

Comment: Yeah the on-line resources are only good for syntax and shallow tips nothing else, thanks I will have a look at that book!

Comment: The programming language really is only like 5% of the job when it comes to digital design.