# Understanding interferring latch in state machine

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

Please take a look at this example code of a simple state machine:

```
entity Top is
    Port ( Clock : in STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           TREADY : out STD_LOGIC
           );
end Top;

architecture Behavioral of Top is
    
    type STATE_t is (S0, S1, S2);
    signal CurrentState : STATE_t := S0;
    
    signal TREADY_Int   : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    
begin

    -- Transit network
    process(Clock, Reset, CurrentState)
        variable NextState : STATE_t;
    begin
        if(rising_edge(Clock)) then
            case CurrentState is
                when S0 =>
                    if(Reset = '1') then
                        NextState := S0;
                    else
                        NextState := S1;
                    end if;
                when S1 =>
                     NextState := S2;
                when S2 =>
                    NextState := S1;
            end case;
        end if;
        
        CurrentState <= NextState;
    end process;

    -- Output network
    process(CurrentState)
    begin
        if(CurrentState = S0) then
            TREADY_Int <= '0';
        elsif(CurrentState = S1) then
            TREADY_Int <= '1';
        elsif(CurrentState = S2) then
            TREADY_Int <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
    
    TREADY <= TREADY_Int;

end Behavioral;
```

The synthesis shows me the following warning:

`[Synth 8-327] inferring latch for variable 'TREADY_Int_reg'`

[image: Schematic with latch]

The warning disappears when I change the last condition of the output network to

```
    else
        TREADY_Int <= '0';
    end if;
```

and also the latch is gone

[image: Schemativ without latch]

So why does the last condition of the output state machine in the first version result in a latch? Why is `else` something other than `elsif()`? In my opinion, the two expressions are equal, because the state machine has only three states, so `else` and `elsif(<ThirdState>)` should be the same when all other states are handled. But it seems that my understanding is wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am getting inferred latches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279873/why-am-getting-inferred-latches)

Comment: No I think not. The linked topic discuss the error during an if-condition with STD_LOGIC where the user doesn´t handled all cases (STD_LOGIC has 9 states) and without a clock, so a latch is pretty normal. This topic discuss the upcomming of a latch in a clocked state machine where all states are handled.

Comment: No. [IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8 Standard synthesis packages, 16.8.2 Interpretation of the standard logic types, 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plvy5.jpg). That there is a latch on TREADY_int for the first synthesis result has nothing to do with base type std_ulogic having 9 enumeration values.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually best not to assume that a synthesiser is as clever as you are. Using `else` is safer as you have discovered.

Here's another example. This is better:

```
process (A, B)
begin
  if (A < B)
    F <= ...
  else
    F <= ...
  end if;
end process;
```

than this:

```
process (A, B)
begin
  if (A < B)
    F <= ...
  end if;
  if (A >= B)
    F <= ...
  end if;
end process;
```